# How to generate OAuth Access Token and Secret on LinkedIn

Tags: python, oauth, linkedin-api

I just created an application on LinkedIn's developer website. I have my client id and secret (API key & secret), but I don't know how to generate the access token&secret. I followed the documentation, but I was unable to generate the access token and secret. Twitter, for example, is much easier when it comes to generating client key, secret & access token, secret. Why do I need this? I'm trying to write a Python script that automates searches on LinkedIn. Can anyone help me, please?

Many thanks in advance.

Best,
Lo

Answer (score 0):

You can use python-linkedin https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this link! I've also come across the python linkedin library, and unfortunately, it didn't work. I will give it another try.

Comment: Hi @HaoyuCai, I've just tried it again and it doesn't work. I followed the instructions - I can't execute these steps: 


Set LINKEDIN_API_KEY and LINKEDIN_API_SECRET, configure your app to redirect to http://localhost:8080/code, then execute:

http_api.py
Visit http://localhost:8080 in your browser, curl or similar
A tab in your browser will open up, give LinkedIn permission there
You'll then be presented with a list of available routes, hit any, e.g.:
curl -XGET http://localhost:8080/get_profile

Does it work for you?